# interface implementation error?

Tags: java, android

I am less experienced in Android and i am trying to download a file in background using Volley library whenever the user receives a push notification from firebase.

I followed this tutorial
https://techstricks.com/download-file-using-android-volley/

My firebase notification receiver class looks like,

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService implements Response.Listener<byte[]>, Response.ErrorListener {
```

My Custom class to download,

```
public class InputStreamVolleyRequest extends Request<byte[]> {
    private final Response.Listener<byte[]> mListener;
    private Map<String, String> mParams;
    //create a static map for directly accessing headers
    public Map<String, String> responseHeaders;

    public InputStreamVolleyRequest(int post, String mUrl, Response.Listener<byte[]> listener,
                                    Response.ErrorListener errorListener, HashMap<String, String> params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(post, mUrl, errorListener);
        // this request would never use cache since you are fetching the file content from server
        setShouldCache(false);
        mListener = listener;
        mParams = params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return mParams;
    }

    ;


    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(byte[] response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<byte[]> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        //Initialise local responseHeaders map with response headers received
        responseHeaders = response.headers;

        //Pass the response data here
        return Response.success(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
}
```

Now when i try to call the constructor of the above class like

```
request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.GET, urltohit, context, context, null);
```

I am getting error in the context being passed.

[image]

Any help would be greatly useful to learn for me

Comment: clearly as you can see from the image, you are passing the wrong context. instead of passing adnroid.content.Context, you need to pass volley.Response.Listener.

Comment: But i have implemented it in my class ...    

implements Response.Listener<byte[]>, Response.ErrorListener

Comment: replace `context` with `this`

Comment: Thanks @shine_joseph, It worked !

Answer (score 3):

> expected params was volleyListener ,error listener and you were passing android context

```
request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.GET, urltohit, this, this, null);
```

Comment: Without  explanation, your correct answer loses from its value.

Comment: added explanation ... thnaks @davidxxx